# Android SDK installer stuck on "Detecting whether Java SDK is installed"

Tags: java, android, windows-7, sdk, adk

Like the title suggests - the *Android SDK r20.0.1* installer won't get past the *"Detecting whether Java SDK is installed"* (picture below).

[image]

I'm running *Windows 7 64 bit*.

My steps:

1. installed both 32 bit and 64 bit Java SDK;
2. I've set my Path (from My Computer>Properties) to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin", the 64 bit version of that and without the \bin at the end AND \jdk1.7.0_05\jre\bin;
3. I've added the Java Development Kit key to Wow6432Node;
4. ran the installer as admin but still, it won't detect the darn thing.

Also, I can't click back OR next OR cancel. Nothing happens when I do, just like nothing happens when I click the X. It won't even shut if I right click and close it so I have to bring out the Task Manager every time to close it.

Note - I'm not extremely tech-savvy so a step-by-step guide to whatever you want me to do (if anything) would be appreciated.

Comment: Hey this is not a duplicate of the many questions "Android SDK installer not detecting Java". I was facing exactly the same issue as the op and resolved by removing all 64-bit versions of java and installing the 32-bit version. Please reopen the question so that I can post the answer

Answer (score 1):

Do detect whether JDK is installed and its path is properly configured or not do the following

- First see whether a `java` folder has been created or not in the place where installed it.
- If you want to check that whether its path has been configured properly, then do this..

Go to command prompt and type the following:

`java -version`

If you get the output something like the below, then you are good to go, else think you have not properly configured its path. And **in the output the version number will be different than its here, depending up on your JDK version**.

```
java version "1.7.0_03"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_03-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 22.1-b02, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: Kumar Vivek Mitra, yes there is a java folder in both Program files ,which is for the 64 bit software, and Program Files (x86).
The "java -version" command returns pretty much the same thing as you've shown, except my version is "1.7.0_05"

Comment: PS: Thank you for the help so far, any other suggestions?

Comment: If you are using Eclipse, please see that can you eclipse find the JDK... can you run a demo java project... Moreover Eclipse always picks up the JDK by its self... but still check it once again

Answer (score 0):

Try to click Back button and re-clicking the install button.
This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved this problem recently by changing the slashes to backslashes.

So instead of C:\MyJavaInstall\Java  use C:/MyJavaInstall/Java

I was surprised, but this was the only thing that worked for me.

Comment: Didn't work, but thank you anyway :)

Answer (score -1):

The reccomended version for Windows is the `JDK 1.6 32 bit`, make sure that you have installed only this one as JDK and all the environmental path are set, especially `JAVA_HOME`.

Developing for Android on Windows is always discouraged.

Comment: It is NOT 'always discouraged' to develop Android for Windows.  It is an officially supported platform, and widely used.  I have no issues using Windows - it is a good platform for development.

Comment: My system only picks up the x86 JDK I've installed (when uninstalling from Programs and Features).  Any idea how I can safely remove the 62 bit version or should I just delete the folder?